# Python convert variables to cases

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to transform a DataFrame from this

```
id track var1 text1 var1 text2
1     1    10    a    11    b
2     1    17    b    19    c
3     2    20    c    33    d
```

Into this:

```
id track var text 
1     1   10   a 
1     1   11   b
2     1   17   b 
2     1   19   c 
3     2   20   c
3     2   33   d
```

I'm trying Pandas stack() method yet it seems to force all columns as respondents and does not keep fixed vales (i.e id track).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `wide_to_long`

```
df.columns=['id','track','var1','text1','var2','text2']

pd.wide_to_long(df,['var','text'],i=['id','track'],j='drop').reset_index(level=[0,1])
Out[238]: 
      id  track  var text
drop                     
1      1      1   10    a
2      1      1   11    b
1      2      1   17    b
2      2      1   19    c
1      3      2   20    c
2      3      2   33    d
```